# Configure wireless access on seperate router with Blueyonder UK (Virgin Media)

Tags: wifi

Current setup:

- Surfboard SB5100i connected via a
  cable modem wire to Blueyonder
  (Virgin Media).
- NetGear WGR614 with
  ADSL wireless modem.

I was planning on using the wireless capabilities of the NetGear in conjunction with the Surfboard cable modem.

The plan was to have the NetGear router plugged into the the Surfboard (using LAN port 1) and have the cable service automatically detect the MAC address of the NetGear and allow it onto the network. So far so good - I have tested this and it works. If I plug a cable into LAN port 2 I can use the internet.

The problem is when using Wireless. I have setup the NetGear as a DHCP server to issue addresses over the wireless connection. The problem is that I am unable to use the internet over wireless, only through LAN port 2.

Its been a long time since I setup a cable modem connection and even a network with two switches(!), what am I doing wrong? Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used a cable modem, but won't it see the MAC address of whatever is sending the packet, i.e. whatever is connected to LAN2. Hosts on the wireless network, or indeed other hosts connected to LAN3 or LAN4 would present a different MAC address.

You'd normally connect your cable modem to the WAN port of an ethernet router like the Draytek 2910 (I'm not sure what the Netgear equivalent is, but there will be one). That way the cable modem only ever sees the MAC address of the router's WAN port.

JR

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the WGR614 isn't trying to provide its wireless clients with Internet access through a non-existent ADSL connection, rather than one of its LAN ports; is it set up as an access point rather than one of its various bridging modes?  Which port on the WGR614 is connected to your SurfBoard?